# Interesting problem about limit points. Found it in my mathematical analysis book.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

The task is to build two sets $A, B \subset \mathbb{R}$, such that $A' = B' = \emptyset$ and $(A + B)' = [0, 1]$, where:

$A' = \text{the set of limit points}$.

$A + B = \{a + b \ | \ a \in A, b \in B\}$.

I think answer should be something like:

$A = \{x + \frac{1}{n} \ | \ \forall x \in [0, 0.5]\}$

$B = \{x - \frac{1}{n} \ | \ \forall x \in [0, 0.5]\}$.

But I'm not sure that's true because I'm new in real-analysis tasks and I don't have a good mentor right now.

Comment: what does $A'$ mean?  The set of limit points?  The set of boundary points?  The complement of $A$?  If $A = (0,1)$ what is $A'$.  Is it:  $[0,1]$? is $\{0,1\}$? is it $(-\infty,0] \cup [1, \infty)$?

Comment: $A'$ is the set of limit points, yes. If $A = (0, 1)$, $A'= [0,1]$.

Comment: Some thoughts to help you focus your search: $A$ and $B$ must be locally finite and thus unbounded. The “integer parts” of the elements of $A$ and $B$ have to be chosen carefully so as to avoid accumulation at a non-zero element.

Comment: So, can you explain me why my answer is wrong?

Comment: @Someone your sets $A$ and $B$ are the closed intervals $[1/n, 0.5+1/n]$ and $[-1/n, 0.5-1/n]$ so $A'$ and $B'$ are nonempty.